# Enum in Plain SQL when using Slick 3.1

Tags: postgresql, slick, slick-pg

I'm using Slick 3.1.0 and Slick-pg 0.10.0. I have an enum as:

```
object UserProviders extends Enumeration {
  type Provider = Value
  val Google, Facebook = Value
}
```

Following the test case, it works fine with the column mapper simply adding the following `implicit` mapper into my customized driver.

```
implicit val userProviderMapper = createEnumJdbcType("UserProvider", UserProviders, quoteName = true)
```

However, when using plain SQL, I encountered the following compilation error:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter e: slick.jdbc.SetParameter[Option[models.UserProviders.Provider]]
```

I could not find any document about this. How can I write plain SQL with enum in slick? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have an implicit of type `SetParameter[T]` in scope which tells slick how to set parameters from some custom type `T` that it doesn't already know about.  For example:

```
  implicit val setInstant: SetParameter[Instant] = SetParameter { (instant, pp) => 
    pp.setTimestamp(new Timestamp(instant.toEpochMilli))
  }
```

The type of pp is `PositionedParameters`.

You might also come across the need to tell slick how to extract a query result into some custom type `T` that it doesn't already know about.  For this, you need an implicit `GetResult[T]` in scope.  For example:

```
  implicit def getInstant(implicit get: GetResult[Long]): GetResult[Instant] = 
    get andThen (Instant.ofEpochMilli(_))
```